# SQL Server : sorting letters with number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not good at SQL - the below is what I have tried so far from searching.
As you can see in the picture the `BarangayName` is not in order. As you can see there is a `'Z , S, and 1'` between the Letter `B` and the `Brgy 10 and Brgy 11` is far from each other.

[image]

```
select * 
from dbo.barangay as a
order by SUBSTRING(a.barangayname, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', a.barangayname), LEN(a.barangayname))
```

Comment: I must be missing something.  If you want to sort by `barangayname`, why not just use `order by barangayname`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I try it but the result is different. If I use `Order by a.barangayname` the result is `barangay 1, barangay 11, barangay 12`

Comment: You should give more detail. For example: your `barangayname` structure, what you want to sort the first by, then the second by ????

Answer (score 1):

I tried to work out something for you.

Let's take following sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table as TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(134,'Brgy 1')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(256,'Brgy 100')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(687,'Sample 1 z1')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(954,'Brgy 11 zn9')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(887,'Brgy 10 zn11')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(785,'Brgy 098 xys')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(785,'Zone 2 wer')
```

The following select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM @Table ORDER BY 2
```

will result as:

[image]

But by using following code, to get a custom sorting for you,

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
    SUBSTRING(name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', name)) sPart,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(name, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', name), LEN(name))))+' ' restPart
    FROM @Table
)
SELECT ID, Name
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY 
    sPart,
    CAST(LEFT(restPart, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', restPart)) AS INT);
```

You can achieve:

[image]

Does that make sense?

**EDIT** *To fix conversion issue*

To avoid conversion issue, replace `ORDER BY` section with following:

```
ORDER BY 
    sPart,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(restPart, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', restPart)))=1 THEN CAST(LEFT(restPart, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', restPart)) AS INT) 
       ELSE 0
    END;
```

Comment: i got this error. `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'B' to data type int.`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is taking the part of barangayname after the first numeric character, and sorting on that. So anything where the first numeric character is 0 will come before anything where the first numeric character is 1.
To sort on the numeric value in the string, you need something like:

```
convert(int, substring(substring(barangayname, patindex('%[0-9]%', barangayname), LEN(barangayname)), 0,patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(barangayname, patindex('%[0-9]%', barangayname), LEN(barangayname)))))
```

Comment: just short answer.. `Barangay 10 , 11 , 12 , ETC` must be in order then next is the `Brgy 099 - 100 , ETC`

Comment: This must be for id 315.  I'm out and can check that part later. Or see if u can check that for now ? I mean run for all other rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .it may help you .

```
DECLARE @Table as TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(134,'Brgy 1')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(256,'Brgy 100')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(687,'Sample 1 z1')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(954,'Brgy 11 zn9')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(887,'Brgy 10 zn11')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(785,'Brgy 098 xys')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(785,'Zone 2 wer')


select ID,NAME,names,position from (
select Id,name,names,posi,convert(bigint,case when charindex(' ',posi)=0 then posi else substring(posi,1,charindex(' ',posi)) end ) as position from(
select ID,Name,substring(Name,1,charindex(' ',Name)) as Names,ltrim(substring(Name,charindex(' ',Name),100)) as Posi from @Table
) as a
 ) as b
 order by names,position
```

Comment: ok i'll explain you that. is that working as what you expect ..??

Comment: I don't know for now because it's hard for me to apply your code.